# How do I add my ORCID to papers authored by myself?

Tags: publications, digital-researcher-id

I have a few papers that have already been accepted and published.
I recently signed up for an ORCID.
Is is possible to add my ORCID to these already published papers,
and if so, how do I do this?

**Response to comment**
Ideally, I would like my ORCID to be listed on the paper itself or on the official website of the journal article.
Nevertheless, I would consider having the paper listed on my ORCID profile to be a good partial solution.

Comment: Do you want your ORCID to be listed on the paper itself/on the journal website, or do you just want your ORCID profile to link to the paper? The latter is definitely possible if you log on to your profile and select "add works", but I don't know about the former.

Comment: @user2390246 See my response to comment in the edited question. You could post the steps to "add works" as a partial answer to my question.

Comment: I've not (yet) seen any journals offering retroactive addition of ORCIDs. It's possible they might do so in future but I wouldn't bet on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible to add your ORCID directly to the paper in question (probably not), but it is possible to link to the paper from your ORCID profile.

- Go to [your ORCID account](https://orcid.org/my-orcid) (signing in if necessary)
- This should bring up a page with your "Biography", which consists of several collapsible tabs (Education, Employment, Funding and Works).
- Next to the Works tab, click on the button for "+ Add works".
- You then have several different options to proceed. The quickest is "search and link" which allows you to search a database such as PubMed or CrossRef, find your paper, and add it to your profile. I won't go through the full details of each step, but if you follow the instructions on screen, it should hopefully guide you through.

Answer (score 1):

This would have to be done by the journal itself. The journal would need to embed your authenticated ORCID iD into the article's metadata, and amend the online version of the article in order to include your ORCID iD.

Retroactively adding an ORCID iD to a published work is no easy task. Like Andrew, one cannot recall any journals or publishers stating that they will retroactively add authenticated ORCID iDs to the metadata of existing published works.

Comment: Please do not add such remarks (for more information email ....) at the end of your answer.

Comment: @wythagoras - How is that spam? The question is **about** ORCID - the email address is support@orcid.org.

Comment: @WaiHaLee I'm stating that it is *not* really accepted at SE to add email address at the end,if the author of the question needs more information, he/she should comment, not have to email.

Comment: @wythagoras the email does not belong to the answerer.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Hence I removed it. Why do you address me?

Comment: @wythagoras Because I have no idea what you are objecting to. The answerer is providing the information needed for the OP to obtain further information.